# How to completely replace a key with `lein change`

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, leiningen

I am pretty new to Clojure, and I'm just getting my head around all the nifty things that leiningen can do. One thing that seems quite cool is `lein change`, which lets you supply a function and arguments to be applied to a key in the `project.clj`. So if you have a `:url` value of `https://www.example.com` you can run

```
lein change url str "/myproject"
```

which runs `(str (:url project) "/myproject")` (assuming the project structure works like a map). Cool.

My question is: is there a pithy way to use `lein change` to completely replace a key? I can see that I would need to supply a function to `lein change` which ignores its first argument, and returns its second. If there was a function like this -- call it `clobber` -- then I could run:

```
lein change url clobber "https://new.example.com"
```

which would turn into `(clobber (:url project) "https://new.example.com")`.

Is there a built-in that works like `clobber`, or do I have to do some black magic with `->>`?

NOTE: I realise that I can just open the file and change the value, but I want to find an elegant solution to this puzzle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lein change` accepts the pseudo-function `set` to mean "replace":

```
lein change url set "http://example.com"
```

Comment: Fantastic thanks. Is this in some documentation somewhere? I couldn't find very much at all about `lein change`.

Comment: It might be. Having never heard of `lein change` before, I just looked at the source for it, and found https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/src/leiningen/change.clj#L32.

Comment: Fair enough. I will make myself a TODO note to send a PR adding this to the lein docs. Looking at that definition, it seems like `lein change url ->> ((constantly "foo"))` should work, _modulo_ some escaping -- if I wanted to solve my question using only real functions/macros from `clojure.core`. Although I can't get it to play ball in practice, possibly because  `->>` is a macro.

Comment: I would be quite surprised if that worked. `lein change` only accepts functions in clojure.core, not functions you build yourself with `constantly`, and certainly not arbitrary clojure expressions.